# htaccess not rewriting correctly

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this ReWrite rule in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

and when i go to:

```
domain.com/reports/helpdesk/tickets_report
```

it shows page not found, other pages seem to work fine

Answer (score 1):

in this line of the htaccess, i needed to add a `_`

So, change:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

to be:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/_]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```